# Set date input field's max date to today

Tags: javascript, html

I just have a simple line of code like this:

```
<input type='date' min='1899-01-01' max='2000-01-01'>
```

Is there a simple way to set the max date to "today" instead of 2000-01-01? Or do I have to use Javascript to do this?

Answer (score 151):

**JavaScript only simple solution**

```js
datePickerId.max = new Date().toISOString().split("T")[0];
```

```html
<input type="date" id="datePickerId" />
```

```js
// below trick also works! Thanks jymbob for the comment.
datePickerId.max = new Date().toLocaleDateString('fr-ca')
```

Comment: @BrandenBarber even `type="date"` is not working on it

Comment: It appears `max` it is not currently supported on iOS Safari. Check here for updates on this https://caniuse.com/#search=input%20date

Comment: thanks for the solution, how avoid that the user write a date that is not permitted, actually with this solution in the pick of the date is right the rule, but permit write a different date of the restriction

Comment: @EdwinVasquez it will be validated upon the form submission. try
```<form> <input type="date" max='2020-12-15' id="dt" required /><input type="submit" value="Submit" /></form>```

Comment: thanks to the helpful folks over in North America: `today = new Date().toLocaleDateString('en-ca')` - avoids odd off-by-one issues when `ISOString()` gets parsed to UTC

Comment: @jymbob Thanks! This is basically helpful for every user/browser that has a timezone offset (not just North America).
It's not so much that 'en-ca' part does anything with the timezone (that's due to the `toLocaleDateString` method) but it so happens that the 'en-ca' locale displays a date in the exact way the input field needs it to be (YYY-MM-DD). So also for any other timezone in the world you should just use 'en-ca' as locale!

Comment: @ArnovanOordt yep, that's why it's so convenient!

Comment: Followup to my comment from 2021: From Chrome 110 `en-ca` no longer gives an ISO-friendly date, instead returning a standard North American m/d/y format. `fr-ca` is still yyyy-mm-dd

Comment: @jymbob thank you for keeping things up to date. I edited the answer.

Answer (score 120):

You will need Javascript to do this:

**HTML**

```html
<input id="datefield" type='date' min='1899-01-01' max='2000-13-13'></input>
```

**JS**

```js
var today = new Date();
var dd = today.getDate();
var mm = today.getMonth() + 1; //January is 0!
var yyyy = today.getFullYear();

if (dd < 10) {
   dd = '0' + dd;
}

if (mm < 10) {
   mm = '0' + mm;
} 
    
today = yyyy + '-' + mm + '-' + dd;
document.getElementById("datefield").setAttribute("max", today);
```

**[JSFiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/dae4y126/)**

Comment: works perfectly.. wish HTML5 natively offered such feature or much flexible date format options

Comment: In addition to the front-end states, depending on the case you probably also need server side validation.

Comment: Umm, I am attempting this, and it won't set the maximum date.. It still lets me select dates outside of the maximum, e.g. if today was the 25th of October, it's letting me select the 26th, 27th, 28th etc. Anyone know why?

Comment: thanks for the solution, how avoid that the user write a date that is not permitted, actually with this solution in the pick of the date is right the rule, but permit write a different date of the restriction

Comment: The "input" element is meant to be self-closing. `<input id="datefield" type='date' min='1899-01-01' max='2000-13-13' />`.

Comment: No idea if its the version I'm using, but if its not in the yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm format its getting ignored.  Just a change to:   `today = yyyy+'-'+mm+'-'+dd+'T00:00';`  fixed it for me

Answer (score 54):

In lieu of Javascript, a shorter PHP-based solution could be:

```
 <input type="date" name="date1" max="<?= date('Y-m-d'); ?>">
```

Comment: You should use a proper templating system instead of mixing HTML and PHP code.

Comment: @bfontaine clearly you haven't use php since in it both html and php is mixed

Comment: @Pulkit The fact that you can doesn’t mean you should.

Comment: @bfontaine mixing is a matter of choice some people like beer some people like cocktails, this example is great and save the manipulations with js or what ever example:

Comment: min 18 years old: <input max="<?php echo date('Y-m-d',strtotime('-18 years'));?>" required  id="date_of_birth" type="date" placeholder="Date Of Birth" name="date_of_birth">

Comment: @talsibony People choosing bad solutions doesn’t make these solutions better in any way. Drinking cyanide or beer is a matter of choice, too.

Comment: @bfontaine solution becomes bad when it creates another problem, I don't think this causing a problem in any way, in general mixing php and HTML in the same file it is not a problem at all.

Comment: @talsibony Hence the "you should". I’m not saying this causes an issue, just that mixing PHP and HTML is a bad idea because it can cause a lot of issues you wouldn’t have with a proper templating system. We’re not in 1999 anymore, we have real tools now.

Comment: Stumbled across this years later and downvoted. You should not be rendering a simple date server side, even if the data is retrieved from a database. Retrieve it, report it, then render with a templating solution or something.

Comment: Same, but shorder: <input type="date" name="date1" max="<?= date('Y-m-d') ?>">

Comment: @Crowes ..... Agree to disagree? I think doing a _simple_ date from the server-side is actually interesting and keeps the method of "getting" the date hidden. I know there really is no _practical_ reason to hide code for getting a date, seeing as W3Schools and those other educational sites will provide the _exact_ same code as you used, if not **simpler or better**.

Comment: @Pulkit you obviouly do not have much experience on how important and critical php can save you time and productivity sprinkled all over a html page. that comes with years of experience and this is a small example you are seeing here. Like one user says here you do not need js to sort issue because of a small php code used well.

Comment: you need to avoid using php for such things because if your web application serves 1M users, it has to do this instruction 1M times. so it's mutch better to do these things in client side .

Comment: This answer go to far, as it force to use PHP.

Comment: @YasserCHENIK Clientside validation cannot be relied upon. No matter what validation you have on the client, you must also validate it on the server, as HTML and JS can be modified by the client.

Comment: @mbomb007 that is not a validation , it's a function that calculates the time and format it  ... instead of using the client device to do it you waist your server recourses to do it ! NOT validation ... server side validation is a must but this is just formatting output !

Comment: great hack for PHP projects. I don't know why some guys are not happy with this. Simply if it doesnt work for you just scroll on... duh!

Answer (score 19):

Javascript will be required; for example:

```
$(function(){
    $('[type="date"]').prop('max', function(){
        return new Date().toJSON().split('T')[0];
    });
});
```

[JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/trixta/h7YdJ/light/)

Comment: And jquery aparrantly

Comment: That's why my solution isn't that great. But the question is still why we can't do this natively without any JS involved

Answer (score 10):

Is you don't want to use external scripts, but rather set the `max` limit right in the HTML input element, inline as so:

```html
<input type="date" max="3000-01-01" onfocus="this.max=new Date().toISOString().split('T')[0]" />
```

I've intentionally added the `max` attribute with a date far into the future, because it seems Chrome browser change the width of the field once a `max` attribute is set, so to avoid that, I had it pre-set.

[See live demo](https://jsbin.com/jekuden/edit?html,css,js,output)

Comment: Best solution here in my opinion, thank you vsync, if anyone is trying to block out past dates like me, try this ```<input type="date" min="2050-01-01" onfocus="this.min=new Date().toISOString().split('T')[0]" />```

Comment: What about if i wanna able to choose last 40 days?

Comment: This topic is about a single date selection, not a range of dates. For selecting a range you would need 2 date inputs and a visual way to select a range which will eventually fill the values for those 2 fields

Answer (score 8):

`toISOString()` will give current UTC Date. So to get the current local time we have to get `getTimezoneOffset()` and subtract it from current time

```js
document.getElementById('dt').max = new Date(new Date().getTime() - new Date().getTimezoneOffset() * 60000).toISOString().split("T")[0];
```

```html
<input type="date" min='1899-01-01' id="dt" />
```

Comment: thanks for the solution, how avoid that the user write a date that is not permitted, actually with this solution in the pick of the date is right the rule, but permit write a different date of the restriction

Answer (score 6):

I am using Laravel 7.x with blade templating and I use:

```
<input ... max="{{ now()->toDateString('Y-m-d') }}">
```

Comment: in my case it didn't work, maybe, can also use this ```date('Y-m-d', strtotime($yourVariable))```

Comment: What if someone needs it only for js. Ans is out of scope for particular question

Comment: Please read the question "Is there a simple way to set the max date to "today" instead of 2000-01-01? Or do I have to use Javascript to do this?" It is about another way than JS.

Answer (score 5):

An alternative to `.split("T")[0]` without creating a string array in memory, using [`String.slice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice):

```
new Date().toISOString().slice(0, -14)
```

```js
datePickerId.max = new Date().toISOString().slice(0, -14);
```

```html
<input type="date" id="datePickerId" />
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes, and no.  There are min and max attributes in HTML 5, but

> The max attribute will not work for dates and time in Internet Explorer 10+ or Firefox, since IE 10+ and Firefox does not support these input types.

**EDIT**: [Firefox now does support it](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/date)

So if you are confused by the documentation of that attributes, yet it doesn't work, that's why.
See the [W3 page](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_max.asp) for the versions.

I find it easiest to use Javascript, s the other answers say, since you can just use a pre-made module.  Also, many Javascript date picker libraries have a min/max setting and have that nice calendar look.

Answer (score 3):

Examples with jQuery and JavaScript:

```js
$('#arrival_date').attr('min', new Date().toISOString().split('T')[0])
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="date" name="arrival_date" id="arrival_date" class="form-control" aria-label="...">
```

```js
document.getElementById('arrival_date').setAttribute('min', new Date().toISOString().split('T')[0])
```

```html
<input type="date" name="arrival_date" id="arrival_date" class="form-control" aria-label="...">
```

Answer (score 2):

it can be useful :
If you want to do it with Symfony forms :

```
 $today = new DateTime('now');
 $formBuilder->add('startDate', DateType::class, array(
                   'widget' => 'single_text',
                   'data'   => new \DateTime(),
                   'attr'   => ['min' => $today->format('Y-m-d')]
                   ));
```

Comment: Introducing Symfony for such a basic requirement looks a bit weird

Comment: Ok, in fact I was here from google and there were "symfony" in my search so I thought it can help

Answer (score 2):

Example with React

```js
import Input from "./components/Input";

const DateInput = () => {
  const today = new Date().toISOString().split("T")[0];
  return <Input type="date" max={today} />
}

export default DateInput;
```

Answer (score 1):

A short but may be less readable version of one of the previous answers.

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(DOM_Load);

    function DOM_Load (e) {
        $("#datefield").on("click", dateOfBirth_Click);
    }

    function dateOfBirth_Click(e) {
        let today = new Date();
        $("#datefield").prop("max", `${today.getUTCFullYear()}-${(today.getUTCMonth() + 1).toString().padStart(2, "0")}-${today.getUTCDate().toString().padStart(2, "0")}`);
    }

</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes... you have to use Javascript. My solution below is just yet another option which you can pick up.

```
var today = new Date().toJSON().slice(0, 10);
var date = $('#date-picker');
date.attr('max', today);
```

Comment: jQuery date-picker is a vastly different component from standard date input.

Answer (score 0):

### Template: `ejs`

Using `Node.js`, `express.js` and template System `ejs`:

```
<input id="picOfDayDate" type="date"  name="date-today"
    value="<%= new Date().toISOString().split("T")[0] %>" 
    min='1995-06-16' 
    max="<%= new Date().toISOString().split("T")[0] %>" 
    class="datepicker" 
>
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to get today's date by

```
const [today] = new Date().toISOString().split('T')
```

Then get the max date

```
  const maxDate = new Date();
  maxDate.setDate(maxDate.getDate() + 30);
  const [maxDateFormatted] = maxDate.toISOString().split('T');
```

Then set the `min` and `max` attributes.

```
  const dateInput = document.getElementById('myDateInput');
  dateInput.setAttribute('min', today);
  dateInput.setAttribute('max', maxDateFormatted);
```

This is working example

```js
const [today] = new Date().toISOString().split('T');

const maxDate = new Date();
maxDate.setDate(maxDate.getDate() + 30);
const [maxDateFormatted] = maxDate.toISOString().split('T');

const dateInput = document.getElementById('myDateInput');
dateInput.setAttribute('min', today);
dateInput.setAttribute('max', maxDateFormatted);
```

```html
<input type="date" id="myDateInput"></input>
```

Answer (score 0):

PHP Base

```
<input type="date" name="date1" max="<?= date('Y-m-d'); ?>">
```

C# Base

```
<input type="date" name="date1" max="@DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")">
```

Answer (score -1):

I also had same issue .I build it trough this way.I used struts 2 framework.

```
  <script type="text/javascript">

  $(document).ready(function () {
  var year = (new Date).getFullYear();
  $( "#effectiveDateId" ).datepicker({dateFormat: "mm/dd/yy", maxDate: 
  0});

  });


  </script>

        <s:textfield name="effectiveDate" cssClass="input-large" 
   key="label.warrantRateMappingToPropertyTypeForm.effectiveDate" 
   id="effectiveDateId" required="true"/>
```

This worked for me.