# HTML5 input type date disable dates before today

Tags: html, forms, date

Is there a way to disable dates before today in HTML5?

```
<input type="date">
```

I tried this

```
<input type="date" min="<?php echo $today; ?>">
```

but this works only on desktop browsers... safari mobile still allow dates prior to today.

Comment: output of `$today`?

Comment: The input type date is not integrate by all browser. I think you must use a JS library. http://caniuse.com/#feat=input-datetime

Comment: @sebastianbrosch the output of `$today` is `2016-07-28`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Set date input field's max date to today](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32378590/set-date-input-fields-max-date-to-today)

Answer (score 15):

Input date must be in **ISO** format (which is supported by mobile browsers).

There is no possible way to do this with pure **HTML5**.

But with Javascript, you can do something like:

```
<input name="setTodaysDate" type="date">
```

and;

```
var today = new Date().toISOString().split('T')[0];
document.getElementsByName("setTodaysDate")[0].setAttribute('min', today);
```

This little script will change the `min` with today's date in ISO format.

Live example here: [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/emrebolat/06xuefmx/)

Answer (score 4):

```js
var today = new Date();
var dd = today.getDate();
var mm = today.getMonth() + 1; //January is 0!
var yyyy = today.getFullYear();
if (dd < 10) {
  dd = '0' + dd
}
if (mm < 10) {
  mm = '0' + mm
}

today = yyyy + '-' + mm + '-' + dd;
document.getElementById("datefield").setAttribute("max", today);
```

```html
<input id="datefield" type='date' min='1899-01-01' max='2000-13-13'></input>
```

Comment: No need for almost all of this code: just use `var today = new Date().toISOString().slice(0,10);`

Comment: @HereticMonkey you have a bit of a problem with ISO cause it might get the next day - it depends on your timezone ..

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
<input type="date" name="bday" min="<?= date('Y-m-d'); ?>">
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are using jQuery try this. First add `id` to your element

```
<input type="date" id="minDate">
```

then in between `script` tag put below code

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var today = new Date().toISOString().split('T')[0];
    $("#minDate").attr('min', today);
});
```

It should work fine

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var today = new Date().toISOString().split('T')[0];
  $("#minDate").attr('min', today);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="date" id="minDate">
```