# How to disable/restrict user to select future and current date in bootstrap datepicker?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, date, validation, bootstrap-4

**Problem Statement:-**
I am using bootstrap datepicker in React JS. I have used type="date" for the date of birth and i do not want user to be able to select current or future dates. How can i do so?

**Code:-**

```
import React from "react";

export default function DatePicker() {
  return (
    <div>
      <div className="col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-3 form-group required">
        <label className="control-label">Date of Birth : </label>
      </div>
      <div className="col-sm-7 offset-1 col-md-8 col-lg-8">
        <input
          className="text-uppercase input-group input-group-lg form-control"
          type="date"
          name="dob"
        />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can have properties of `min` and `max`, you have to set max value till today, so all future dates will be disabled to select by users,

```
<input
  name="Fecha_end" 
  id="Fecha_end"
  className="text-uppercase input-group input-group-lg form-control"
  type="text"
  name="dob"
  max= new Date().getFullYear()+'/'+(new Date().getMonth()+1)+'/'+new Date().getDate();
/>
```

full working example here, https://jsfiddle.net/hmLpfkts/1/

Comment: Sir, i appreciate your answer but your working code is in Jquery and i don't want to use it in my React code. Please give me some solution which is feasible for ES6/ES7 syntax.

Comment: @Anshul you can directly try `react-date-picker` dependency suitable with react, refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49850917/how-do-i-disable-future-dates-in-reactjs