# How to disable previous date in javascript date picker. It should be in pure javascript no Jquery only javascript

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, datepicker

If the current time is more than 6 P.M so i want to disable all previous date as well as future 2 date in date picker so the user can select date from the after tomorrow other wise if current time is less than 6 P.M then user can select date from tomorrow but all previous dates should be disabled. 
Only in Javascript not in JQuery.

Comment: Similar like `minDate,maxDate`

Comment: thats in Jquery

Comment: I need it in Javascript

Comment: If you are using input type `date` then [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32378590/set-date-input-fields-max-date-to-today) will help

Answer (score 0):

**JavaScript only simple solution**

```js
datePicker.max = new Date().toISOString().split("T")[0];
```

```html
<input type="date" id="datePicker" />
```

This will set max date you can similarly set min date