# How to stop user from typing in future dates in date type input in angular

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, datepicker

I have restricted users to enter date in future in an input using html 5 date picker. But users are able to type in future dates. Is there any way to stop users to typing in future dates if they don't choose to select date value from date picker calendar?

Here is my code:

**HTML**

```
  <div class="col-sm-7">

    <input type="date" class="form-control" [max]="maxDate" pattern="^(19[5-9][0-9]|20[0-4][0-9]|2050)[-/](0?[1-9]|1[0-2])[-/](0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])$" name="Datebillabuse" [(ngModel)]="Datebillabuse" #date="ngModel" [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': f.submitted && date.invalid }" required />
    <div *ngIf="f.submitted && date.invalid" class="invalid-feedback">
        <div *ngIf="date.errors.required">Date is required</div>
        <div *ngIf="date.errors.pattern">Please enter a valid date</div>
        <div *ngIf='date.errors.max'>Date must not be in future</div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

**TypeScript**

```
  setTodayDate() {

    const dtToday = new Date();
    let month = String(dtToday.getMonth() + 1);
    let day = String(dtToday.getDate());
    let year = dtToday.getFullYear();


    if (parseInt(month, 10) < 10) {
        month = '0' + month.toString();
    }
    if (parseInt(day, 10) < 10) {
        day = '0' + day.toString();
    }

     this.maxDate = `${year}-${month}-${day}`;

  }
```

[image: With calendar drop-down]

[image: Problem when user starts typing future dates]

One solution I thought of is to check date value whether it is greater than today and show error.

Is there any better way to solve it in Angular?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32378590/set-date-input-fields-max-date-to-today

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a problem with html input type date element when we restrict user by setting maximum attribute as this does not let users to select date from calendar drop-down but still users can type in undesired values using keyboard. So this is the hack, I have used to cope with this problem

1. Declare a boolean to check if date is invalid.

   futureDateError: boolean;
2. Declare a method to check if input date is valid.

   checkDateValidity(date: string): boolean
   {

   ```
       const mxDate = new Date(this.maxDate);
       const inputDate = new Date(date);

       if (inputDate > mxDate) {
         return this.futureDateError = true;
       }
       return this.futureDateError = false;
   ```

   }
3. Bind this method with `(change)` event.
4. Show errors when date is  invalid and don't submit form.

   Date must not be in future

   if (this.checkDateValidity(this.Datebillabuse)) {
         return;
       }