# HTML input date: Don't allow user to type future dates using keyboard

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I can easily stop the user from writing future dates using the arrows or the keyboard arrows as you can see below, I want also to prevent him from writing future dates in the input field.

I don't want to disable keyboard input completely though because it's useful

```js
    document.getElementById("date_end").addEventListener("change", event => {
        if (event.target.value > event.target.max) {
            event.target.value = event.target.max;
        }
    });
```

```html
<input type='date' name='date_end' id='date_end' max="2023-01-03" value="2020-01-01">
```

Comment: Possible duplicate:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32378590/set-date-input-fields-max-date-to-today

Comment: @Josh It's not a duplicate, all of the answers there, don't prevent keyboard input from setting a date greater than today, unless I missed an answer. I don't want to set a max date, as you can see from my code, I already did that. I want to prevent keyboard input from being greater than today. I don't want to disable keyboard input either.

Comment: Did you try anything?

Comment: @Lynob you don't want to use custom input field with hidden native input element ?

Comment: @KalimahApps I tried https://www.reddit.com/r/learnjavascript/comments/dwf26t/html_input_date_dont_allow_user_to_type_future/f7itsjj?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x, edited my question to add the snippet, I asked this question here and on 2 subreddits, I try whatever answer I receive.

Comment: @ConstantinTrepadus If that works, I could use that

Comment: @Lynob I updated your OP with a running version of your code, and it _seems_ to be working fine. What is the issue?

Comment: @Lynob Just to be clear. Max and min are working fine. You need the user to click and add the date through the picker rather than a keyboard input?

Comment: @Neal problem solved, waiting to see if the guy who answered on reddit would like to answer here as well, he deserves the rep.

Comment: @KalimahApps problem solved, waiting to see if the guy who answered on reddit would like to answer here as well, he deserves the rep.

Comment: @Amessihel problem solved, waiting to see if the guy who answered on reddit would like to answer here as well, he deserves the rep.

Comment: @Lynob can you post what "worked" as an answer?

Comment: @Neal I wished that one of the reddit users who helped me post an answer here, but since they didn't, I posted an answer.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The snippet above works, but I ended up using the snippet below, not sure why, using the code above is better.

```js
 const dateToDate = date => {
  let params = date.split('-');
  params[1]--; // months are zero indexed
  return new Date(...params);
 };

 let end_date_input = document.getElementById('date_end');
 end_date_input.addEventListener('input', function(){
  if(dateToDate(this.value) > dateToDate(this.max)){
   this.value = this.max;
  }
 });
```

```html
    <input type='date' name='date_end' id='date_end' max="2023-01-03" value="2020-01-01">
```

Comment: I am confused as to what this changes

Comment: @Neal, at first I thought it changes something, then I discovered that it does nothing the other didn't, but I deployed this one on all operations so I regret it. Both work perfectly.

Comment: Minus one for not being sure why you used the much less readable code that does the same thing as the previous code.