# Changing input type="date" min-attribute value with javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net-core

I have two input type="date" fields and I'm trying to change the min-attribute of the name="endDate" field to be 1 day more than the selected value of the name="startDate" field. Could someone please help me with this?

These are my two input fields:

```
<input type="date" id="startdateid" asp-format="{0:dd.MM.yyyy}" class="form-control-with-bottom-margin" name="startDate" min="@startDateMinValue.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")" onchange="SetMinEndDate();" required />
<input type="date" id="enddateid" asp-format="{0:dd.MM.yyyy}" class="form-control-with-bottom-margin" name="endDate" min="@endDateMinValue.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")" required />
```

And this is my best attempt so far. But obviously it's not working because I'm in desperate need of assistance. :D

```
function SetMinEndDate() {
document.querySelector("#enddateid").setAttribute('min', (addDays(document.querySelector("#startdateid").val(), 1)).Date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"));
}
```

Comment: First of all, you need to fix your HTML, because you have double quotes inside double-quoted attributes. Your JS doesn't work, because the HTML is broken.

Comment: @Robo Robok - I think this is a combination of ASP.NET code and HTML. The @ sign would be rendered on the server, so this isn't really broken HTML

Comment: @keyBOardMAN - does this answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32378590/set-date-input-fields-max-date-to-today

Comment: What exactly is not working?

Comment: I got it to work. I took a somewhat different approach. Thanks to everyone who tried to help.