# Setting input type date min value to current date angular 12

Tags: html, angular, typescript, forms, input

I have an input date-picker and I want to set its min value to the current date

`<input type="date" class="form-control" id="checkindate" placeholder="" min="">`

how can I do this using Angular?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Set date input field's max date to today](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32378590/set-date-input-fields-max-date-to-today)

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways to do it. The `min` attribute accepts a string in multiple formats. Here is my solution using `'yyyy-mm-dd'`.

**Controller (*.ts)**

```js
export class AppComponent {
  currentDate: string;

  constructor() {
    // credit: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38148759/6513921
    this.currentDate = new Date().toISOString().slice(0, 10);
  }
}
```

**Template (*.html)**

```html
<input type="date" class="form-control" id="checkindate" placeholder="" [min]="currentDate">
```

Working example: [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-sqphpj?file=src/app/app.component.html)

Answer (score 0):

**You need to pipe the date to follow the input format.**

[Here Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-triyfr?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Comment: <input type="date"  class="form-control" id="checkindate" min="{{date | date:'yyyy-MM-dd'}}">

Comment: Please find a demo with using the pipes Angular, maximum date and minimum date! 
Thank you