# Show only today's and upcoming days' dates to select in html input type date

Tags: javascript, html

```html
<label class="whitetext">Select Date:</label>
<input type="date" class="form-control" name="pickup_date" required>
```

I have this input field in my html file. I want to make it such that the user can select a date starting from today only and not past dates.
I think it can be done using `min` but I dont know how to set `min` to today's date.

Example-->If today is 27th October 2021, then only date 27th and all future dates are accepted as input or past dates are cancelled out or unselectable or something.

Comment: get today date using javascript in one variable and assign the variable to html `min` attribute of date input type

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Set date input field's max date to today](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32378590/set-date-input-fields-max-date-to-today)

Answer (score 2):

You can use setAttribute to set the min with javascript.

```
let today = new Date()

let year = today.getFullYear()
let month = today.getMonth() + 1 // the months are indexed starting with 0
let date = today.getDate()

let dateStr = `${year}-${month}-${date}`

let input = document.querySelector('[name=pickup_date]')
input.setAttribute('min', dateStr)
```