# how to change both input type and max value in react input tag during onfocus?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

i have an input tag .by default it will have type as text but during onfocus type should be changed to date and max should be changed to current date. initially i'm using input type as text since i want an placeholder which says 'Select start date'. i'm building an React application. how to do this?

Comment: May I know why you're not keeping the input type date from the start instead of keeping it as a text?

Comment: i want to put an placeholder. that's the reason why i'm using input type as text initially

Comment: This feels like an XY problem: a placeholder should be used to indicate the expected value of the field, not just an arbitrary label.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var Foo = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function () {

    return {
      type: 'text',
      max: false
    };
  },
  onFocus: function () {

    this.setState({
      type: 'date',
      max: new Date().toISOString().split("T")[0]
    });
  },
  onBlur: function () {

    this.setState({
      type: 'text',
      max: false
    });
  },
  render: function () {

    return(
      <input 
        type={ this.state.type } 
        max={ this.state.max }
        onFocus={ this.onFocus } 
        onBlur={ this.onBlur } 
        placeholder="Enter your date here."
      />
    )
  }
});

React.render(<Foo/>, document.body);
```

Answer (score 0):

In plain JS you could just do somthing like this (shoutouts to TRiNE for originally [posting](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49916376/8241382) the today's-date-code):

```js
const input = document.getElementById('myInput')

input.addEventListener('focus', changeToDateType)

function changeToDateType(){
  input.type = "date"
  input.max = new Date().toISOString().split("T")[0]
}
```

```html
<input id="myInput" placeholder="Enter date here...">
```

Comment: thanks for this. but i need it in react

Answer (score 0):

```
var Foo = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function () {

    return {
      type: 'text'
    };
  },
  onFocus: function () {

    this.setState({
      type: 'date'
    });
  },
  onBlur: function () {

    this.setState({
      type: 'text'
    });
  },
  render: function () {

    return(
      <input 
        type={ this.state.type } 
        onFocus={ this.onFocus } 
        onBlur={ this.onBlur } 
        placeholder="Enter your date here."
      />
    )
  }
});

React.render(<Foo/>, document.body);
```

Comment: how to set max for date type from this?