# Set date input field's minimum date to today

Tags: javascript, html, date

I have a line of code shown below.

```html
<input type='date' min='2022-01-01'></input>
```

Is there a way I can set the minimum date to 'today' using JavaScript, such that any date before today's date won't be valid?

Comment: No, it doesn't. I need to set the min date to today. Not the max. The soliutions described there are also somewhat confusing for me to follow.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```js
document.getElementById("date").min = new Date().toISOString().split("T")[0];
```

```html
<input id="date" type='date'></input>
```

Source: [Just change max to min.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49916376/9977151)

Comment: *toISOString* will return the UTC date, so will be ±1 day from the local date for the period of the local offset from midnight. So for someone in say Sydney, Australia it will produce yesterday's date until 11 am. It is also much better to set the *min* attribute, not the property, so that resetting the form doesn't reset the *min* attribute value.

Comment: Also, *input* elements are empty, the closing tag is entirely superfluous.

Comment: @RobG I just copied OP's code and the principal from https://stackoverflow.com/a/49916376/9977151 .

Comment: @RobG According to the spec, assigning to an input's `min` _property_ will transform the element's _attribute,_ because `min` is an [_IDL attribute_](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/common-dom-interfaces.html#reflecting-content-attributes-in-idl-attributes) of type `DOMString`.

Comment: Also, closing tags on [_void elements_](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#void-elements) are not superfluous but **forbidden in HTML5;** [_self-closing_ is superfluous](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/syntax.html#start-tags:void-elements-2). XHTML requires [_empty elements_](https://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/#h-4.6) to be (self-)closed, but recommends to use self-closed empty elements [for HTML4 compatibility](https://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/#C_2). But make sure to **use modern HTML5 syntax** in the future, folks!

Comment: @OskarGrosser—yes, you're correct regarding IDL attribute. I've yet to find any sensible reason to maintain compatibility with XHTML, which was a short and unsuccessful detour on the path from HTML 4 to 5.

Comment: @ATP—if you are copying someone else's code, you should say so. The fix to the UTC date issue is in the answer you (incompletely) copied.